# operator name for kernel

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I'm trying to define `\newcommand{\ker}{\operatorname{ker}}` just after `\begin{document}` in order to have a nice way to write the kernel of an application but the command is ignored and I don't know why since I put `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package offers `\ker`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
X=\ker f.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want an upper-cased variant, you can use \DeclareMathOperator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}

\begin{document}

\[
X=\Ker f.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax for \DeclareMathOperator is

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\xxx}{yyy}
```

and using `\xxx` in the document body will produce `yyy` in the proper font and will automatically add proper spacing on either side when necessary.

For new operators with subscripts and superscripts placed in "limits"
position above and below, use the `*` form:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\xxx}{yyy}
```

Comment: Suppose that I want to use the same command `\ker` for `Ker`. What do you suggest? I did `\DeclareMathOperator{\kker}{Ker}\renewcommand{\ker}{\kker}` but I don't know if it is the more elegant way.

Comment: @Sigur yes, that's an option, but I'd prefer to store the original definition, just in case. I'd use something like `\makeatletter
\let\oldker\ker
\def\ker{\mathop{\operator@font Ker}\nolimits}
\makeatother`; in this way, `\ker` produces "Ker" and `\oldker` preserves the original definition.